# How to connect with IdM (redhat) using Ruby to get users list

Tags: ruby, ldap, redhat, kerberos, identity-management

Using Ruby, I want to be able to connect to the Red Hat Identity Management System and retrieve a list of users that belong to a specific user group.

I know that you are able to get and search for users using the ipa command if you are on the server (as per the documentation in [this link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Identity_Management_Guide/about-client-tools.html#ipa-command-displaying)). However, I want to do this remotely like when you connect to an LDAP server.

Any suggestion how can I do that? can I do it through the LDAP library or interface in Ruby?

Comment: I know nothing about Red Hat, but can you get the data using shell commands? If so, you could do it in Ruby using backticks.

Comment: I do not know how to do it in shell commands also

Comment: The point is, I know the commands to retrieve the users if you are in the same server (using the ipa command as per the link here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Identity_Management_Guide/about-client-tools.html#ipa-command-displaying) but I want to do this remotely like when you connect to an LDAP server.